# Linux: Speeding up traffic destinated to the bridge itself

Tags: linux, linux-networking, bridge, bridge-router

I am attempting to follow [this advice to speed up traffic destinated to the bridge itself](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/examples/basic.html#ex_speed). My situation seems to check all the boxes: server also talks to other hosts, bridge ports don't have IP addresses, routing table is correct, etc. However, when I apply the rule, the box becomes unreachable from the network. I have to flush the table to get back in.

The only bridge port is a bond device, which may be complicating the issue. Distro is Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS. Here's my netplan:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    trunkports:
      match: { name: "eno[1234]" }
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [trunkports]
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        lacp-rate: fast
  vlans:
    bond252:
      link: bond0
      id: 252
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bond0]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
      addresses:
        - 10.1.10.2/24
        - 10.1.10.10/24
      gateway4: 10.1.10.1
    br252:
      interfaces: [bond252]
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.252.2/24
```

EDIT: I suspect that the "noqueue" queuing discipline that's set by default on all virtual (i.e. bond and bridge) devices means that this performance tweak is no longer strictly necessary, but I would like confirmation on this point.

EDIT 2: Here's the ebtables command I'm issuing:

```
/sbin/ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -d $(< /sys/class/net/br0/address) -p ipv4 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
```

Comment: @anx Added. I have no way of measuring the "after" cf. the "before" because all traffic stops after issuing the command.